# Is deep soil mixing necessary for compacted clay soil before planting a tree?

Tags: soil-amendment, clay, tilling

I am a newbie gardener, and would like to plant around 15 polyalthia longifolia trees in my garden.

The main problem here is that my garden's reddish-clay-soil seems to be compacted.

- Clay sticks under my sandals.
- No worms in the compacted soil.
- Rainwater doesnt drain easily, and on some spots he rainwater doesnt drain eventhough i have digged a hole at 50cm depth, and when i digged deeper i found out that the house-developer had buried their building debris around 50cm under the surface. Digging further than to pass through the debris and the water can then drain normally. The device i used to dig is [this](https://id-test-11.slatic.net/p/fefbc58ad80bd21fc8e706cf0e30fadd.jpg).

My main concerns are that:

- The trees will have their growth stunted because they cannot break through the compacted clay soil, especially there's building debris underneath.
- Combined with bad drainage, the root can also rot.
- Also compaction doesnt provide a lot of pores that are good for root growth.

So i did some online searching on how to make the soil porous, enabling good water drainage, mixing compacted clay soil with organic matters to create a good environment for the trees and i came to this conclusion:

- That i should dig the soil,
- Remixing the soil with rich top soil, small-sized pumice stones, rice husks + rice husk biochars, composts
- And water the soil with EM4.

What i am unsure is that how deep should i dig and remixing the soils ?
Should i go to 1 meter depth ? Because the tree can grow very tall, so i assume the root would go deep also.

From my further reading online articles, some advised to avoid digging to deep because the soil will sink deeper with time, causing the tree's root collar to be lower than the soil surface, and in the end will help fungus grow and make the trees sick. Maybe i just need to raise the soil height on the plantation spots to address this issue ?

Another concern: As per my experience with polybags containing the mixture above, the soil becomes porous indeed with good water drainage, but it seems that the plants do not have stable soil to attach to, and i had to repositioned the plants from time to time to prevent them falling sideways.

Or maybe all of these are just too much for tree planting and that i should just skip soil amendment ?

Comment: My main concern is that the polyalthia longifolia can survive in a situation with such poor drainage. I can find no information on the cultural needs of these trees, so cannot help with this. Another concern is rainy/dry seasonality. Is this common where you live? When I gardened in similar clay soils (we made pottery from it), a drought would turn the "soil" into a cement-like surface. Is it feasible to call someone in to physically remove the clay from the topsoil with machinery? If so, and if this doesn't affeect drainage into buildings, then that would be my recommendation.

Comment: Hi @Jurp I'm living in Java island, Indonesia, Banten to be exact. I'm currently experimenting mixing the 'fresh' reddish clay soil with existing clay soil (it was red, but now just a bit brownish, most probably due to erosion caused by compaction) from manual drilling .. And i intend to add wood chips as mulch. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of the polyalthia longifolia (false ashoka tree) grow deep. However, the primary concern here is not that the roots will be obstructed by the buried debris. Once the plant grows to that size, it will have enough power for its roots to dig through the broken debris. The main concern is the clayey top soil, which will prevent both water and sufficient air to pass through when the plant is young.

For optimum growth of your plant, I think that you should dig up to 1 meter of your clayey soil, as you have contemplated. However, there is a better way to augment your soil. I would suggest that you avoid any organic matter including rich top soil from elsewhere, and just mix your dug up clayey soil with coarse sand in a three to one ratio (three part clayey soil to one part sand). Sand with a coarse grain is needed, similar to the yellow or brownish sand used in construction works. Sands with finer grain would not work here. The main reason to avoid organic matter and to go with coarse sand is that organic matter decays over time, so the porosity as well as the volume of the mixture would decrease, causing the soil to *sink*. Using coarse sand would alleviate these problems. Depending on the desired porosity, you may increase the sand proportion up to a one to one ratio with the clayey soil. Check that water now drains satisfactorily.

After preparing this soil mixture and filling up the dug hole with it apart from the new plant, mix some organic fertilizers on the top soil. It is enough to mix the organic fertilizers only 6-10 cm deep. Over time, it will seep downwards with water. Water your young plant regularly but do not over-water, and in time, it will grow into a majestic tree.

Comment: I disagree with mixing the sand and the clay, because you are essentially creating a clay flowerpot around the tree. It's far better to just dig a whole the depth of the rootball and twice its width, break up the soil you remove as much as possible, and use it to backfill around the tree. The pore spaces around the tree's roots will be the same so there will be no hesitation for the roots to move into the clay surrounding the planting hole. Putting any amendments (especially organic, so I'm with @joy here) is a bad idea, as the roots are likely to stay in the hole and not move into the soil.

Comment: I wrote from my practical experience. Only breaking the compacted clayey soil and use only it to fill up the hole will increase porosity initially, but with continued watering, the broken up clayey soil will again get compacted due to its very nature, unless something with coarse grain is mixed with it, which would not decompose over time.

Comment: I, too, wrote from practical experience. Compaction is caused by vehicle parking, vehicle travel, and lots of foot traffic (i.e. a footpath) . With none of those present, the settling that occurs is not considered to be "compaction" because it doesn't affect the pore sizes in the same way as traffic does. The tree roots won't care. If you're going to use sand, you'll need at least a 2:1 ratio. Covering the site with woodchips is the best way to improve the soil structure. For more information: https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/soil-amendments-2.pdf

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insights @joy, I really feel enlightened.

Comment: @Jurp Digging the depth of the rootball has been mentioned in several sites i googled. What I couldnt comprehend is that how the root can penetrate the compacted undrilled soil below the rootball ?

Comment: Roots of many plants are extremely good at travelling long distances both shallowly and deeply. For example, a perennial called Liatris can have roots that travel 3 meters deep, and oak and hickory trees can have very deep tap roots. They've been doing this for many years without human help :)

Comment: Thanks @Jurp for sharing your experiences !

Comment: I'm going to do manual drilling the existing soil, remixing with 'fresh' red clay soil, and intend to add small sized pumice stones(inspired by the coarse sand) -- and definitely no organic matters ..  hopefully with the current rainy season, the soil will 'sink' and finally normalize to a point of no sinking anymore which signals me to plant the trees. I've also drilled some biopores to prevent erosion, so hopefully this works well for my future trees. Wish me luck !

Comment: Best of luck @AlbertGan in your endeavor. I am sure that all this works of yours will result in some majestic trees over time.